# why Preproccessor is not a part of java programs like C & C++?

Tags: java, toolchain

As in C/C++ the program is first given to the preprocessor to include files & perform macro expansions etc... then given to the compiler to convert the code into assembly format and the process goes on.But in Java I do not see the use of preprocessor.Why so and then who does all the task that normally the preprocessor handles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pre-processor is not a necessary step of the compilation process in Java.

In C/C++, functions stored in different files are "included" in other files, which essentially means they are copied and pasted in their entirety into the document. This was a pretty good idea at the time, given the hardware capabilities at the time, but nowadays more modern languages use something called "symbolic imports".

Symbolic imports involve looking for symbols in another file rather than using text directly. In Java, this can involve importing constants or classes. These imports act as references to code in other files. Thus, rather than having to go through the trouble of having the pre-processor copy and paste code around and eventually figuring out what code belongs to which file, Java allows doing these imports on a semantic level directly.

This makes a pre-processor unnecessary to the compilation process of the language, and has therefore, along with other reasons been left out.

Comment: Sir, what is a semantic level? Could you please give me an idea of it.!

Comment: A compiler makes a distinction between text (its input), tokens (bits and pieces that make sense to it, such as numbers and keywords), and a parse tree of those tokens (knowing which piece of code represents the expression of an if statement). When you look at code at a semantic level, you know its structured (it's parsed), and you know what each symbol within it means. You are thus able to see which constants have been defined, which class(es) are there, and so on. Analysing code at this level is referred to as a semantic level because you are working at a level (...)

Comment: (continued) where you are looking at the meaning and structure of a piece of code as opposed to looking at plaintext. It is here other duties of the compiler can be fulfilled such as type checking and optimisation, because the intent, meaning and structure of the code being compiled is known.

Comment: @OswaldVinny: If this answer was helpful, please make sure to mark your question as aswered.